# Showing an image from LocalStore in HTML on PhoneGap/Cordovia on Windows Phone 7

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone

What is required to show an image from LocalStorage in HTML markup on PhoneGap running on Windows Phone 7?

- an image is downloaded from the Internet and stored on the phone (on Windows Phone 7 it can be stored only in LocalStorege of the application's domain);
- this image is to be shown using PhoneGap \ Cordova HTML markup with `<img>` element;
- using `<img src="xyz"/>` ain't working;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite different from Android version.

Following steps are necessary:

- load the image from localstore as binary data;
- place it in the "src" attribute of the img element encoded;

Code:

```
var fileName = 'myappname/test.png';

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFail);

function onFileSystemSuccess (fileSystem) {
  fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, null, gotFileEntry, onFail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(onGotFile, onFail);
}

function gotFile(onGotFile) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    $('#outerDiv').html('<img src="' + evt.target.result + '" />');
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
}

function onFail(evt) {
  console.log('error: ' + evt.target.error.code);
}
```